# Laravel: view data formatting

Tags: laravel, view, formatting, data-processing

Question: where should one put all the logic for view data processing?

Example:

A page is requested to display a Post. The view post.blade.php has various parts that are displayed differently depending on what the user has done previously (giving a thumbs up for example). Other parts of the same view need to display some formatted text, combining various model fields, that doesn't originally come with Post model. In short, some major processing goes on.

1. I guess I could do all that inside a view, but isn't it better to have a view that is clean of any php code?
2. I thought about making view helpers to cope with this. Like:

   ```
   class PostViewHelper {

       private $post;

       // decide which image to display
       public function getImage1() {
           // check if user has already given a thumbs up
       }  
       // decide how to display text
       public function getText1() {
       // construct a text using post fields
       }
   }
   ```

   A view would use this object to display data to the user.
3. There's also this view composer thing. Perhaps this is the place to have all the display logic? PostViewComposer would do all the work and pass formatted data to the view.

What would you suggest?

Comment: I would do it all in views. If thumbs up use this view, if not use another.

Comment: Going *all javascript* and fetching the data from ajax is also an option.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in multiple way. It's good to make your blade template clean.

You can it using Service Injection(https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#service-injection)

```
@inject('metrics', 'App\Services\MetricsService')

<div>
    Monthly Revenue: {{ $metrics->monthlyRevenue() }}.
</div>
```

Or you can create your own blade directive(https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade)

The following example creates a `@datetime($var)` directive which formats a given `$var`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Blade;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Perform post-registration booting of services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        Blade::directive('datetime', function($expression) {
            return "<?php echo with{$expression}->format('m/d/Y H:i'); ?>";
        });
    }

    /**
     * Register bindings in the container.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

The final PHP generated by this directive will be:

```
<?php echo with($var)->format('m/d/Y H:i'); ?>
```

Or you can use view helper to do some logic. Like https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/helpers#method-e But you have to auto load it in your `composer.json` file like https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/composer.json#L87